# JS interrupting each other on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use two different versions of jQuery on my website. Because i need to use one plugin that is using different version of jQuery than my site. I tried to use noConflict and i even made that plugin to work, but my site didnt work properly. Any idea?

```
<script src="comment/frontend/view/default/javascript/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="comment/frontend/view/default/javascript/jquery-ui/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="comment/3rdparty/read_more/read_more.js"></script>
<script src="comment/3rdparty/filer/filer.js"></script>
<script src="comment/3rdparty/timeago/timeago.js"></script>
<script src="comment/frontend/view/default/javascript/common.js"></script>
<script src="comment/3rdparty/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="comment/3rdparty/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
These last two are using $
<script src="js/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: what error are you getting in console .. you have to use `jquery.noConflict()` though

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).filer is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (clients1.php:638)
    at i (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: I tried to use this                                                                                
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

Comment: is that coming from filer.js? can you share the required jquery versions for all your plugins in the question ?

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569634/how-can-i-use-plugins-for-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page this describes the same scenario with steps

Comment: If i add $old = $.noConflict( true ); after all <script> Then that plugin is working but site is not working properly. I have this in console Uncaught TypeError: select.select2 is not a function and its coming from script.js. Plugin jQuery is v1.12.4... I am sorry i dont have a lot of experience with jQuery

Comment: in script.js you have to replace all `$` with `$old` if you have used `.noconflict` before that. what is the content of script.js and and core.min.js?

Comment: Its working.Script.js are Global variables, core.min.js there are all plugins. Now i have this in my console. Its coming from core.min.js.                           
 JQMIGRATE: 'hover' pseudo-event is deprecated, use 'mouseenter mouseleave'                                                           
                                                                      
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack() 
                                                                                    
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string